# Store Password to the database as Hash MD5 C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, hash

I got a question.. Currently I have this in the database:

```
User ID Username Password
1.      Fuhans   ( Password )
```

How do I make, when I add a new user through my program and store it in the access database, the password to be automatically converted to something like "d4567890123iwo", but inside it there is a password. So user won't know our password.

So, the database will be like this:

User ID Username Password
1.      Fuhans   ( Password ) + ( MD5 )

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use MD5. It's a fast hash and entirely unsuitable for keeping passwords secure. Use something else like SHA-256/512.And don't forget to salt it.

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server for hash password, you can use hashbytes function.
for exampe:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', 'Password'); 
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'Password');
```

Comment: Don't help him compromise the passwords, show him how to do it right!

Comment: declare @password as nvarchar(max) = HASHBYTES('SHA1', N'123');
Insert into [User] values ('1','user', @password)